# Adding CCK fields to Simplenews email newsletter

Tags: 6, entities, emails

I am designing a newsletter using [Simplenews](http://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews), however I need to add a couple of additional CCK fields to each node included in the newsletter. Seeing as the template file the email newsletter uses (simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php) simply uses a $body variable to output content, where would I instruct simplenews to add my additional CCK fields to each of the nodes I am sending?

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it's pretty in deoth on what files and variables you can use with simplenews and cck in Drupal 6: http://drupal.org/node/268404